# Multiple Scanners DoWhile HiLo (10-sided Dice game)

Tags: java, windows-7, java.util.scanner, do-while, bluej

I have created a game that prints a random roll number between 1 & 10. The system then asks the user if they want to guess higher [1] or lower [2] for a second roll number. Based on their guess the system will print either "Draw!", "You guessed wrongly." or "You guessed correctly." which works correctly using two nested if clauses as:

```
public class Short {
public static void main(String args[]) {

        //roll one
        int rNum1 = (int)(Math.random() * 11); //declare random roll one,  gives result between 1 and 10

        //print roll one
        System.out.println("You roll the 10-sided die."); 
        System.out.println("It lands on " + rNum1 + ".");
        System.out.println(); //space

        //User guess
        Scanner choice = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Will a second die roll higher or lower?");
        System.out.println("To guess higher enter [1], or to guess lower, enter [2].");

        //roll two
        int rNum2 = (int)(Math.random() * 11); //declare random roll two
        int guess = choice.nextInt(); //user's guess / HiLo

        //print roll two
        System.out.println(); //space
        System.out.println("You roll the die again."); 
        System.out.println("It lands on " + rNum2 + ".");
        System.out.println(); //space

    if (guess == 1) //guessed higher
    {
        if (rNum1 == rNum2)
        {
            System.out.println("Draw!");
        }
        else if (rNum1 > rNum2)
        {
            System.out.println("You guessed wrongly.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You guessed correctly!");
        }
    }

    if (guess == 2) //guessed lower
    {
        if (rNum1 == rNum2)
        {
            System.out.println("Draw!");
        }
        else if (rNum1 > rNum2)
        {
            System.out.println("You guessed correctly!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You guessed wrongly.");
        }
    }
}
```

Though I want to give the user an opportunity to play again if they so wish by entering [y] or [n]. I attempted to use a do-while loop to achieve this declaring a second scanner ("replay"):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random; 
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Short {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    String replay = in.next(); //game replay scanner

    do{

        //roll one
        int rNum1 = (int)(Math.random() * 11); //declare random roll one,  gives result between 1 and 10

        //print roll one
        System.out.println("You roll the 10-sided die."); 
        System.out.println("It lands on " + rNum1 + ".");
        System.out.println(); //space

        //User guess
        Scanner choice = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Will a second die roll higher or lower?");
        System.out.println("To guess higher enter [1], or to guess lower, enter [2].");

        //roll two
        int rNum2 = (int)(Math.random() * 11); //declare random roll two
        int guess = choice.nextInt(); //user's guess / HiLo

        //print roll two
        System.out.println(); //space
        System.out.println("You roll the die again."); 
        System.out.println("It lands on " + rNum2 + ".");
        System.out.println(); //space

    if (guess == 1) //guessed higher
    {
        if (rNum1 == rNum2)
        {
            System.out.println("Draw!");
        }
        else if (rNum1 > rNum2)
        {
            System.out.println("You guessed wrongly.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You guessed correctly!");
        }
    }

    if (guess == 2) //guessed lower
    {
        if (rNum1 == rNum2)
        {
            System.out.println("Draw!");
        }
        else if (rNum1 > rNum2)
        {
            System.out.println("You guessed correctly!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You guessed wrongly.");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Enter [y] for yes.");
}while(replay == "y");
}
```

However the entire loop intialises as an infinite loop. How would I fix my dowhile using multiple scanners? I realise I'm quite a noob to java. Do I want to use a do while loop to allow the user to replay after the first run?

Comment: you do not need to create a new scanner from System.in, just use the same scanner object you created

Comment: you are using replay == "y", you should be checking if replay.equals("y"), you should also place String replay = in.next(); inside the do logic

Comment: check out the answer i submitted. i used all of your code with slight modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You were close but try grabbing input with the scanner object using nextLine() then parse the input into the integer. Then at the end just ask to see if the user wants to play again.

```
        String replay = "y";
        Scanner choice = new Scanner (System.in);
        while(replay.equals("y"))
        {

            //roll one
            int rNum1 = (int)(Math.random() * 11); //declare random roll one,  gives result between 1 and 10

            //print roll one
            System.out.println("You roll the 10-sided die."); 
            System.out.println("It lands on " + rNum1 + ".");
            System.out.println(); //space

            //User guess
            System.out.println("Will a second die roll higher or lower?");
            System.out.println("To guess higher enter [1], or to guess lower, enter [2].");

            //roll two
            int rNum2 = (int)(Math.random() * 11); //declare random roll two
            int guess = Integer.parseInt(choice.nextLine()); //user's guess / HiLo

            //print roll two
            System.out.println(); //space
            System.out.println("You roll the die again."); 
            System.out.println("It lands on " + rNum2 + ".");
            System.out.println(); //space

            if (guess == 1) //guessed higher
            {
                if (rNum1 == rNum2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Draw!");
                }
                else if (rNum1 > rNum2)
                {
                    System.out.println("You guessed wrongly.");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("You guessed correctly!");
                }
            }

            if (guess == 2) //guessed lower
            {
                if (rNum1 == rNum2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Draw!");
                }
                else if (rNum1 > rNum2)
                {
                    System.out.println("You guessed correctly!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("You guessed wrongly.");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Enter [y] for yes.");
            replay = choice.nextLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

With regards to asking to play again, encapsulate your code in a 'while' loop, e.g.

boolean playAgain = true;

```
while (playAgain == true)
  {
      your code...
  ......
  ""Ask the user if they wish to play again (y/n), and change this to true or false accordingly.
```

This will allow the game to loop over until the player doesn't wish to play again.

Answer (score -1):

after prompting the user you are not taking input. read his reply before checking it.
The infinite loop is due to the fact that the user's initial reply was 'y', so the loop will either execute infinitely or not at all (when the first reply is 'n')